# Use the principle of mathematical induction to prove [(1/2)+(1/2)+(1/3)+. . . (1/n)] ≤ (n/2)+1 for all n ϵ z+

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

Use the principle of mathematical induction to prove $$\left[\frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}\right] \leq \frac{n}{2} + 1~\text{for all}~n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

I have been trying to solve this however find myself getting stuck when I substitute $p_k$ back into the equation. This is my approach so far:

(1) If $n= 1$, LHS $= (1/1) = 1$ and RHS $= \frac{1}{2}+1 = \frac{3}{2}$
LHS $\leq$ RHS
$p_1$ is true

Assuming $p_k$ is true, $n = k$

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{k}{2}+1$$

If $p_{k+1}$ is true, $n = k+1$

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k+1}  \leq \frac{k+1}{2} +1$$
Now LHS $\leq  \frac{k}{2}+1+ \frac{1}{k+1}$ [using $p_k$]

I don't really know what to do after this in terms of proving the sequence is less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2} + 1$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that if it is true for k, it is true fro k+1.

for k>1 let's assume that p[k] is true, then
(1/1)+(1/2)(1/3)...(1/k) ≤ (k/2)+1

we want to prove that p[k+1] is true in other words :

(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)...+(1/k)+(1/(k+1))≤(k+1)/2 +1
we have (k+1)/2 + 1 = k/2 + 1/2 + 1 = k/2 + 1 + 1/2

with p[k] we can write :
(1/1)+(1/2)(1/3)... + (1/k) + 1/(k+1) ≤ k/2 + 1 + 1/(k+1)
we also know that k>1 so 1/(k+1) < 1/2
so we have :
(1/1)+(1/2)(1/3)... + (1/k) + 1/(k+1) ≤ k/2 + 1 + 1/2
so we have proved p[k+1]

Comment: Thanks heaps :)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}$,

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k+1} &\leq \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&=(\frac{k}{2}+1 )+\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{k+1}{2}+1
\end{align*}$

The second to last line comes from the hypothesis which we assumed is valid for $n=k$.

Comment: Thankyou I think this is a useful way to look at it it.